# ++ operator overload - loop does not terminate without reference

Tags: c++, reference, operator-overloading

Can someone explain why the below loop in `main()` does not terminate

```
#include <iostream>

enum day {
Sunday,     // 0
Monday,     // 1
Tuesday,    // 2
Wednesday,  // 3
Thursday,   // 4
Friday,     // 5
Saturday,   // 6
not_a_day   // 7
};

day operator++(day d) {
    d = (day)(d + 1);
    return d;
}

int main() {
    day d;
    d = Sunday;
    while (d <= Saturday) {
        ++d;
    }
    std::cout << d << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I change the overloaded operator to use references, it works as expected, returning `7`.

```
day &operator++(day &d) {
    d = (day)(d + 1);
    return d;
}
```

Example taken from [here](http://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/programming-pointers/4024641/An-Introduction-to-References).

I also do not understand why the compiler is able to *cast `day` to an `int`* with the `+` operator, but is not able to do so for `++`?

Comment: Your overloaded operator has no side effects; it leaves its operand unchanged. As written, `++d` is a no-op. Read about passing by reference in your favorite C++ textbook.

Comment: thanks, that resolved with `d=++d`.

Comment: If you follow your linked tutorial you'll see that you need to use `day &operator++ (day &d)` so that you pass a mutable reference. Otherwise you can't edit the original `day`.